# How to Set SPQuery.RowLimit to get all items?

Tags: splist, spquery, html, spview

I'm using my SPList View to get the html code of extracted items by an SPQuery over the listview

```
SPList myList = mySite.RootWeb.Lists.GetByInternalName("ListINStr");
SPView oView = myList.Views["ViewTitle"];
SPQuery myQuery = new SPQuery(oView);
string MailHTMLBody = myList.RenderAsHtml(myQuery);
```

But since SPQuery.RowLimit is not defined it's set to a limited number of the view which I believe it's 30 however I need to get them all items , so how can I set myQuery.RowLimit to extract all items ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
myQuery.RowLimit = 0
```

I think if I'm correct: 0 = unlimited

Hope this helps. :)